Android resource linking failed, ziparchive, Entry at offset zero has invalid LFH signature, error: failed to open APK: Invalid file
I encountered an error while trying to build my Android project:
Android resource linking failed
     ziparchive W 05-09 20:34:28 24864 23328] Zip: Entry at offset zero has invalid LFH signature cdd8ecd8
     error: failed to open APK: Invalid file.

I created a new Android project in Android Studio Jellyfish using Java 17. I'm facing the error described below. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?
PS: I tried with Build/Clean, Build/Rebuild, Invalid Cache, ... but it didn't work for me.
Here is my full log:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ziparchive W 05-09 20:34:28 24864 23328] Zip: Entry at offset zero has invalid LFH signature cdd8ecd8
     error: failed to open APK: Invalid file.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2m 48s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            168.8s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

